# elements placed before javascript but getElementById returns null javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Don't know how this is supposed to work, but here goes.  So the issue that I am seeing at the moment is I am unable to get a value from a getElementById when the element exists before the script to run.  I have been unable to find anything via google or stack overflow.  If I am barking in the wrong area, truly I apologize.  Below is the offending code.  I think?!?  Again please forgive.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
  <title>Testing Masking</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input name='EmailAddress' type='text' maxlength='255' />
  <input name='maskTest' />
  <button id='maskButton'>Test
  </button>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('maskButton').onclick = function() {
      var test = document.getElementById('maskTest').value;
      console.log(test);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As I said I am unable to get any value other than null back to the console.  Thanks if you guys can help.

Comment: If you're importing jQuery, you might as well use it.

Comment: The `name` attribute is required on form elements so that they can submit their name and value to another location. The `id` attribute is for identification in HTML, CSS and JavaScript. It's common on form elements to put both a `name` and an `id` and to use the same identifier on each so that you can do all the things you'll want to do with the form element.

Comment: Thanks Pointy.  JQuery isn't one of my strong suits but you are right.  If I wrap it correctly in an example..... it worked.  Hard to see the forest for the trees sometimes.  Thanks for the help too SM.  That worked as well, when working through this stuff it's sometimes difficult to see all the aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an element with an `id` of `maskTest`. Presumably you're just missing the attribute from the `name="maskTest"` element.

Also note that using `onclick` is considered outdated now. It's much better practice to use `addEventListener` instead. Try this:

```js
document.getElementById('maskButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var test = document.getElementById('maskTest').value;
  console.log(test);
});
```

```html
<input name="EmailAddress" type="text" maxlength="255" />
<input id="maskTest" name="maskTest" />
<button id="maskButton">Test</button>
```

Or alternatively you could use jQuery as you've added it to your page anyway:

```js
$('#maskButton').on('click', function() {
  var test = $('#maskTest').val();
  console.log(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="EmailAddress" type="text" maxlength="255" />
<input id="maskTest" name="maskTest" />
<button id="maskButton">Test</button>
```

Comment: probably should change button to <button type="button" id="maskButton">Test</button> if you do not want the button type to default to submit.

Comment: In OPs case theres no form, so its not a problem

Comment: I noticed that but not everyone knows that.

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry my comp has been out of juice for a bit but your help is much appreciated.  Putting it in JQuery format worked...... Hate it when I get so focused that I can't use examples properly.